php | create a file in htdocs in Ubuntu
I use Ubuntu & XAMPP. I can't create a file in htdocs and linux won't let me
I was able to create a directory with the terminal command(touch command), but I can't create a file with the .PHP extension there, can anyone help me?
I used VS Code for this, but VS Code still doesn't allow me to create the file myself.
All I was able to do was create a directory in htdocs using the terminal
Use terminal to create a file with php extension. This was unsuccessful.
Also, using VS Code to create a file in htdocs, which was still unsuccessful.

If you can't create a file, you might have better luck over at superuser.com. You'll need to provide a bit more information, such as the exact directory and any error messages.  Make sure the user creating the file has write/execute permissions on that folder.

The directory permissions have to allow the webserver user (usually something like www-user) to create files.

Thank you for your help. My problem was solved with root user
